# In India where I get enrolled for Cetification Course (Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Application Development(Exam:70-573))?

Tags: 2010

In india where can I enrolled my self for SharePoint 2010 Certification Course(Exam 70-573). I am waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Prometric? They're a global provider of certification:

http://www.prometric.com/Microsoft/default.htm